# Maven: command not found: mvn

Tags: maven

My maven stopped working all of a sudden.
I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.6. Maven is installed in Applications directory. It was working fine for over an year. My .bash_profile has

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export M2_HOME=/Users/vn0gdpo/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MacOS has recently changed the default shell to zsh and the output shows you are running zsh.  You now need to update `$HOME/.zshrc` and `$HOME/.zlogin` (or change your login shell back to `bash`: `chsh -s /bin/bash`).